# How can I prevent the unbalanced calls method during a container transition?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm getting the "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for " when I transition between child view controllers.

I'm pretty sure it's because I add a the child view controller and then the transitionFromViewController methods adds it again.

But I need to add the subview to setup the constraints for auto layout.

```
@IBAction func flipAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var nextViewController = self.currentViewController == self.frontViewController ? self.backViewController : self.frontViewController

    self.currentViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    self.addChildViewController(nextViewController)

    nextViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.frame
    self.containerView.addSubview(nextViewController.view)
    nextViewController.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    self.containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[back]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros, metrics: nil, views: ["back": nextViewController.view]))
    self.containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[back]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros, metrics: nil, views: ["back": nextViewController.view]))

    self.transitionFromViewController(self.currentViewController, toViewController: nextViewController, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: { () -> Void in

    }) { (success: Bool) -> Void in

        self.currentViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
        nextViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        self.currentViewController = nextViewController
    }
}
```

How can I prevent the unbalanced calls method?

Comment: From the docs "The removeFromParentViewController method automatically calls the didMoveToParentViewController: method of the child view controller after it removes the child." - not entirely sure what that means, but have you tried removing the call to `nextViewController.didMoveToParentViewController`?

Comment: I can't confirm just yet, but the options argument in transitionFromViewController lets you OR UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews which states "If both views are already part of your view hierarchy, you can include the UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews option in the options parameter to simply hide or show them."